# TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED when swapping token for eth with uniswap api

Tags: ethereum-classic, uniswap, ethers.js

when calling uniswap.swapExactTokensForEth, I get the following error on etherscan:

Fail with error: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED

I see previous posts with this error, though they seem related to not approving the token for selling.

I've already done that though manually, and have manually sold the token, but for some reason using the uniswap API, it fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: How much tokens were previously approved? If the approved balance was already used you have to call approval again.

Comment: I see, but lets say for https://app.uniswap.org/, you approve once through the UI, and then you never have to approve again right? At least thats how its worked for me, your saying with using the API though it works differently? And that you need to approve each time before the swap?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "call approval again"? I just approved it though app.uniswap.org, do you mean approve it in a different way?

Comment: Check how much allowance have left querying the token contract.

Comment: I see there's an "allowance" function in the read contract part of the token contract. For owner address, is that my address? And spender is uniswap address?

Comment: Owner is the token owner and spender is the contract calling `transferFrom()`.